# get the next running date of a cron expression with 6 fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'd like to get the next running date of a cron expression that contains 6 fields (Seconds,Minutes,Hours,Day of month,Month,Day of week,Year; see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

I found some good python module that supports 5 fields but not 6.

Is there any by any chance?

Thanks,
V.